# Remove Hotseat (app dock) in android nougat launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to remove hotseat (app dock) in homescreen view, i was trying to edit launcher.xml, launcher.java, hotseat.xml, hotseat.java, but nothing changed. do u have any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with changing the following line in file \res\values\dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="dynamic_grid_hotseat_height">88.0dip</dimen>
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you want exactly?

If you are working on AOSP Launcher (branch Android_7.1), you need to modify AllAppsContainerView.java, Launcher.java, Workspace.java, DeviceProfile.java etc.

It is not depended on .xml layout files. If you remove hotseat, app won't work.

I guess you want to remove hotseat completely. If i guess correctly, you need to modify measurement codes. DeviceProfile.java has Layout() method. you can find hotseat measurement and modify height as 0(Zero) and modify workspace, you need to remove hotseat paddings from getWorkspacePadding() method.

Otherwise, Please write more details.

Comment: I solve with change file \res\values\dimens.xml

<dimen name="dynamic_grid_hotseat_height">88.0dip</dimen>

Comment: Thank you !! Best solution !